# Define finite ordered set using nested tuples

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My book on set theory has this exercise:

> Define n-tuples so that
>
> 1) $(a_0) = a_0$
>
> 2) $(a_0, a_1,...,a_n) = ((a_0, a_1,...,a_{n-1}), a_n)$ for all $n \geq 1$

I don't understand what I have to do here. Another way to express an ordered set of objects $a_0, a_1,...,a_n$ has already been developed in the book using a sequence (a function with domain $n+1$ and codomain $\{a_0, a_1,...,a_n\}$). But now the author wants to develop it another way using nested tuples.

Another thing which confuses me is that I am given objects $a_0, a_1,...,a_n$, which are already in order, I know that $a_7$ is after $a_6$. So I am trying to find a way to express order when I already use order implicitly.

**I have come up only with this way**: if we have one element, namely $a_0$, we can define what we want and prove its uniqueness using part 1 of the definition. Suppose we can define it for $n$ elements, then using part 2 of the definition we can define it and prove uniqueness for $n+1$ elements, and hence for any $n \in \Bbb N$.

I don't think my understanding is correct. Can you express me as precise as possible in terms close to logic what I have to prove or existence of what I have to show. Because the author uses informal way of explaining which is not clear to me.

Comment: I think that you have to generalize the "standard" set-theoretic def of *ordered couple* : $(x,y)= \{ \{ x \}, \{ x, y \} \}$ in this way : *(i)* $(a_0)=a_0$; *(ii)* $(a_1,\ldots, a_{n+1}) = ((a_1,\ldots, a_n), a_{n+1})$ proving the basic property : If $(a_1,\ldots, a_n) = (b_1,\ldots, b_n)$, then $a_i = b_i$, for $1 ≤ i ≤ n$.

Comment: You don't have to do anything here. The book is doing all the work. You just have to read and understand the definition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You sound like you know where it is from (it is from Baby Jech). Actually I have to solve this problem, the author provides a long hint for this exercise. I didn't read the hint when I asked this question, but then I read it because I was confused. Or you want to say that if there is a hint, you must read it. I   choose to try to solve a problem before reading the hint.

Comment: I have no idea where it's from (well, now I do, although I'm not sure what "baby Jech" means). But the question you posed is not a "problem" to be solved. It is just a proposed definition, there's nothing to be solved there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: *Baby Jech* is "Introduction to Set Theory," when *Papa Jech* is "Set Theory." I have just coined this names :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define an *n-tuple* his way: I had to come up with a property $P(x, y)$ and state that an object $a$ is an *n-tuple* if it satisfies the property $P(a, n)$. Then I had to prove 1) and 2) parts as theorems.

So parts 1) and 2) are not the way to define it, they have to follow from your definition.

Look at the whole hint the author provides for this exercise:

[image]